# Multiple sort numeric before string

Tags: php, algorithm

I would like to know how to sort numeric before string. I use array_multisort to sort my array.

There is my sample data

```
$arr = [
    [
        'company_name' => '',
        'expiryDate' => '2018.7',
        'classification' => 1
    ],
    [
        'company_name' => '',
        'expiryDate' => '2018.7',
        'classification' => '2-03'
    ],
    [
        'company_name' => '',
        'expiryDate' => '2018.7',
        'classification' => 3
    ],
    [
        'company_name' => '',
        'expiryDate' => '2018.7',
        'classification' => '2-01'
    ],
];
```

The current result after sort. The string numeric '2-01' is sort between 1 and 3

```
$arr = [
    [
        'company_name' => '',
        'expiryDate' => '2018.7',
        'classification' => 1
    ],
    [
        'company_name' => '',
        'expiryDate' => '2018.7',
        'classification' => '2-01'
    ],
    [
        'company_name' => '',
        'expiryDate' => '2018.7',
        'classification' => '2-03'
    ],
    [
        'company_name' => '',
        'expiryDate' => '2018.7',
        'classification' => 3
    ],
];
```

My expected result. I want to sort string '2-01', '2-03' after the numeric 1 and 3

```
$arr = [
       [
          'company_name' => '',
          'expiryDate' => '2018.7',
          'classification' => 1
       ],
       [
          'company_name' => '',
          'expiryDate' => '2018.7',
          'classification' => 3
       ],
       [
          'company_name' => '',
          'expiryDate' => '2018.7',
          'classification' => '2-01'
       ],
       [
          'company_name' => '',
          'expiryDate' => '2018.7',
          'classification' => '2-03'
       ],
    ];
```

My sort fields. I used array_multisort to sort multiple fields

```
$sortFields = [
    'classification' => SORT_ASC,
    'company_name' => SORT_ASC,
    'expiryDate' => SORT_ASC
];
```

Comment: Write a custom comparator with `usort($arr, function($a1, $a2) {})`

Comment: What do you mean by "sort numeric before string"? Can you give an example output?

Comment: @Mike I added example output

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Could you give me some suggestion when sort multiple fields

Comment: Did you try to remove dashes(-) to dots and convert to float in classification?

Comment: @Sakezzz That's not what the OP wants. See the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [usort()](http://php.net/usort) for this:

```
usort($arr, function($a,$b) {
    // First, sort by classification. If it returns non-zero, use this
    // sort. If not, move to the next sort type.
    $sort = sortByClassification($a['classification'],$b['classification']);
    if ($sort !== 0) {
        return $sort;
    }

    // Second, sort by company name. If it returns non-zero, use this
    // sort. If not, move to the next sort type.
    $sort = sortByCompanyName($a['company_name'],$b['company_name']);
    if ($sort !== 0) {
        return $sort;
    }

    // Third, sort by expiry date. Since this is the last sort type,
    // we can just return it
    return sortByExpiryDate($a['expiryDate'],$b['expiryDate']);
});

function sortByClassification($a,$b) {
    // Both are numeric, so sort numerically
    if (is_numeric($a) && is_numeric($b)) {
        if ($a == $b) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    // Both are strings, so sort alphabetically
    if (!is_numeric($a) && !is_numeric($b)) {
        return strcmp($a, $b);
    }
    return is_numeric($a) ? -1 : 1;
}

function sortByCompanyName($a,$b) {
    return strcmp($a, $b);
}

function sortByExpiryDate($a, $b) {
    $a_explode = explode('.', $a);
    $a_expiry = new DateTime($a_explode[0].'-'.$a_explode[1].'-1');

    $b_explode = explode('.', $b);
    $b_expiry = new DateTime($b_explode[0].'-'.$b_explode[1].'-1');

    if ($a_expiry == $b_expiry) {
        return 0;
    }
    return $a_expiry < $b_expiry ? -1 : 1;
}

print_r($arr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [company_name] => 
            [expiryDate] => 2018.7
            [classification] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [company_name] => 
            [expiryDate] => 2018.7
            [classification] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [company_name] => 
            [expiryDate] => 2018.7
            [classification] => 2-01
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [company_name] => 
            [expiryDate] => 2018.7
            [classification] => 2-03
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you for helping but I want to sort multiple fields , How could I do it with usor?

Comment: I've updated my answer, however it's mostly untested.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I not test all these function above but the function for classification sort is correct. I will mask your answer is correct answer, but actually I like the answer is remove dash and convert it to float, it can solve my question.

Comment: How would converting it to a float solve your question when you want "2-01" to appear after "3"?

Comment: When remove dash and convert it into float. This "2-01" -> 201 therefore it larger than 3.

Answer (score 2):

Try with [`usort()`](http://php.net/usort) and a comparator:

```
// @param $arr array that you want to sort
// @param $sortby sort by $arr[$indexOfArray][$sortby]
// @param $isDate boolean
function sortItOutYourself(&$arr, $sortby, $isDate) {
    usort($arr, function($a1, $a2) use ($sortby, $isDate) {
        if($isDate)
            return DateTime::createFromFormat("Y.m", $a1[$sortby])->getTimestamp()
                - DateTime::createFromFormat("Y.m", $a2[$sortby])->getTimestamp();

        if( (gettype($a1[$sortby]) == "string" && gettype($a2[$sortby]) == "string") ||
            (gettype($a1[$sortby]) == "integer" && gettype($a2[$sortby]) == "integer") )
            return $a1[$sortby] > $a2[$sortby] ? 1 : -1;

        return gettype($a1[$sortby]) == "integer" && gettype($a2[$sortby]) == "string" ? -1 : 1;
    });
}

sortItOutYourself($arr, "classification", false);
sortItOutYourself($arr, "company_name", false);
sortItOutYourself($arr, "expiryDate", true);
```

Comment: Thank you for helping but I want to sort multiple fields , How could I do it with usor?

Comment: There are lot of examples in usort link that I have written with the answer. You can refer it for more details. You should learn to create a comparator as the very first step.

Comment: If you sort by `company_name` and then by `classification`, you will lose any sorting you did when sorting by `company_name` because it resorts the entire array again. You've also missed the cases where the values are equal, and you need to return 0.

Comment: Or maybe I misunderstood the question and the OP wanted to sort by those 3 things independently instead of consecutively in a single sort.

Comment: I want to sort it consecutively not independently. Therefore the answer from @AniketSahrawat is not correct , and event if I try to sort only one thing `classification` independently , the sort result is not correct

Comment: Do you understand how it works? You will have to sort it one by one if you want to have a readable code or write at least 50 lines to just *sort it consecutively*. Both ways will result the same. Anyways, thankyou for telling me that my answer is wrong.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I understand how it work but I have thought that your answer will resolve my question, and not only me is misunderstand, Mike also too. Anyway thank for your help

Comment: "*Both ways will result the same*" - Actually yeah, I see that now. However to get the same result, you have to sort the columns in reverse order to what you actually want. So if you want them to be sorted primarily by `classification` then by `company_name`, then by `expiryDate` you have to sort the array first by `expiryDate`, then `company_name` then `classification` and it would give the same result as my answer. You just have to include the part about `expiryDate`, which you left out. Do that and I'll upvote your answer.

Comment: @Mike Updated :) Not for a upvote, but because *You just have to include the part about expiryDate*.